# make Chrome script breakpoints persistant between page (re-)loads

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I have scripts that run when the document loads. But to see changes I've made to the page, I must reload it, and this clears out all the breakpoints I've set in my script. Is there anyway to make those breakpoints persistant from pageload-to-pageload? It seems like Chrome used to do this automatically, but doesn't anymore. Thanks

Comment: what version on what platform do you use?

Comment: @loislo Version 22.0.1229.79 on OSX 10.7.5 64bit thanks

Comment: It is 3 versions older than chrome stable.

Comment: @loislo `chrome://chrome/` shows "✓ Google Chroms is up to date.". Is there some way to manually update it without have to do a re-installation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add the instruction

```
if (my_dbg != undefined) {
    debugger;
}
```

to your scripts. If you want to enable breaks, then somewhere add a:

```
var my_dbg = true;
```

Not too elegant, but should resolve your issue.

For exaple:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#submit_me').click(function () {
      if (my_dbg != undefined) {
        debugger;
      }
   });
   // do other important things...
   if (my_dbg != undefined) {
        debugger;
    }
   // moar important things follow, need to debug
});
```

Before loading the page again, popup js console and type

```
var my_dbg = true;
```

then hit reload. Should work just fine.

Comment: Thanks! Can you show me exactly how you'd implement this in a code block?

Comment: Aha. Well, it definitely stops the page loading, but typing variables to the sources panel or console doesn't show their values. Shows them as undefined. Thanks.

Comment: you have to define the variables in the console, use the entire var name = value, so you're defining the variables and enabling the breaks. If this don't work, just add var declaration in some script that is executed before your piece of code.

Comment: Haha, nope! It was just that the variable actually _was_ undefined. And that was my problem. Works perfect. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 0):

In the sources tab of Chrome developer tools you should be able to click a line number and get a blue arrow. This will set a breakpoint that will persist between page loads.

Comment: this is the normal way to make a breakpoint, but it does not persist through page reloading for me. thanks!

Comment: I mostly added my comment for people not familiar with chrome-dev-tools. :) I've had the opposite problem of breakpoints NOT clearing after being unset before a page reload. Glad to see you got it solved.